# List being empty when it shouldn't be

Tags: python, list, pygame, append, rect

This is my relevant code...

```
def start_room(): 
    global r_x 
    global r_y
    tile_rects = []
    screen.blit(floor1_floor, (0, 0))
    r_y = 0
    for layer in startroom:
        r_x = 0
        for tile in layer:  
            if tile == '2':
                bat_create()    
            if tile == '1':
                screen.blit(grass, (r_x*40, r_y*40))       
                tile_rects.append(pygame.Rect(r_x*40, r_y*40, 40, 40))
            r_x += 1
        r_y += 1
```

The function `start_room()` Is only called once. What is meant to happen is that `tile_rects` gets emptied, then in `if tile == '1':` squares are blitted onto the screen, and rectangles are then made for these squares. For some reason, when I call the function without `tile_rects = []` and I print `tile_rects` all the values for the rectangles exist. When I call the function with `tile_rects = []` none of the values exist. This would be fine, but I need to clear the array before using it. Does anyone know how to solve this? Thanks!

Comment: `global tile_rects`?

Comment: note, that is a list, not an array

Comment: Where are you printing the tile_rects from?

Comment: this function, that you provide, do nothing with tile_rects. You should print it or return it from function, in other case tile_rects value will be missing

Comment: Thanks for all the help. Global-ing `tile_rects` worked perfectly. Thanks for correcting my calling lists arrays as well :)

Answer (score 0):

A variable declared inside the function's body or in the local scope is interpret as a local variable. If you want to set a variable in the global namespace in the scope of a function, you must use the [`global` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html?highlight=global#grammar-token-global-stmt):

```py
def start_room(): 
    
    global tile_rects 

    tile_rects = []

    # [...]
```